# Как записать цикл for в одну строку

Tags: python, циклы

Например мы выводим через for слово привет 3 раза и нам надо записать привет 3 раза в одну строку.

Comment: К примеру так `“привет“*3`

Comment: Похоже, дело не в фор, а в выводе. Используете print? Посмотрите ее описание в хелпе

Answer (score 2):

Первый вариант:

```
for _ in range(3): print('hello', end=', ')
```

Второй вариант:

```
print(', '.join(['hello' for _ in range(3)]))
```

Comment: квадратные скобки можно убрать

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вам for?

```py
print(', '.join(['hello']*3))
```

Comment: зачем вам join?

Comment: @eri, чтоб запятые между словами расставить, а вы думали зачем?

Comment: print(*(["hello"]*3),sep =", ")

Comment: @eri, согласен) можно и так, хотя на пару символов длиннее.

Comment: @eri, можно убрать скобки `print(*["hello"]*3,sep=", ")`

Comment: можно, так не читается вторая звездочка

Comment: вторая звездочка выполняется первой.

Comment: да, но не читается человеком

Comment: @eri, вы считаете, что вы общаетесь с искусственным интеллектом? ) мне кажется синтаксис - это дело наживное.

Comment: как говорит @avp - не стоит превращать питон в перл.

Comment: @eri, все зависит от требований, в данном случае так писать не возбраняется.